# How to get the directory of a file from the full path in C

Tags: c, string, file, path

I'm trying to dynamically obtain the parent directory (let's say `C:\some\dir`) from a file name I get in an argument (say `C:\some\dir\file`), and put it in a `char*`. I already have the full path and file in a `char*`. How exactly would I do that in C?

I have some code but in my mind it's all garbled and I can't make any sense of it. How should I rework/rewrite this?

```
/* Gets parent directory of file being compiled */
    short SlashesAmount;
    short NamePosition;
    short NameLength;
    char* Pieces[SlashesAmount];
    char* SplitPath;
    short ByteNumber;
    short PieceNumber;
    char* ScriptDir;
    NameLength = strlen(File);

    //Dirty work
    SplitPath = strtok(File, "\");
    do {
        ByteNumber = 0;
        do {
            File[NamePosition] = CurrentPiece[ByteNumber];
            NamePosition++;
        } while(File[NamePosition] != '\n');
        PieceNumber++;
    } while(NamePosition < NameLength);
```

Comment: Use [`char *strrchr(const char *string, int c);`](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Frtref%2Fstrrchr.htm) do `strrchr(File, '\\') = '\0';` note `strtok()` modifies first argument.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What you're looking for is [`dirname(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dirname.3.html). This is POSIX-only.

A Windows alternative would be [`_splitpath_s`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8e46eyt7.aspx).

```
errno_t _splitpath_s(
   const char * path,
   char * drive,
   size_t driveNumberOfElements,
   char * dir,
   size_t dirNumberOfElements,
   char * fname,
   size_t nameNumberOfElements,
   char * ext, 
   size_t extNumberOfElements
);
```

Sample code (untested):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
const char* path = "C:\\some\\dir\\file";
char dir[256];

_splitpath_s(path,
    NULL, 0,             // Don't need drive
    dir, sizeof(dir),    // Just the directory
    NULL, 0,             // Don't need filename
    NULL, 0);
```

Comment: Isn't it specific to Linux?

Comment: Oh my God thank you so much. You saved me a nightmare.

Comment: Note: `_splitpath_s` this does not return the drive with the `dir`. So the sample above will only return `\\some\\dir`, and **not** `C:\\some\\dir`. So if you are working on a file that may not be on the C drive, you'd have to use `_splitpath_s` to get the drive and the dir, then combine them using  `_makepath_s`.

Answer (score 6):

You already have the full path of the file (for example: C:\some\dir\file.txt), just:
1. find the last slash by strrchr() : called p 
2. copy from the beginning of the path to the p - 1 (do not include '/')
So the code will look like:

```
char *lastSlash = NULL;
char *parent = NULL;
lastSlash = strrchr(File, '\\'); // you need escape character
parent = strndup(File, strlen(File) - (lastSlash - 1));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int len = strlen(filepath);  
char* dir = malloc(len + 1);
strcpy(dir, filepath);
while (len > 0) {
   len--;
   if (dir[len] == '\\' || dir[len] == '/') {
      dir[len] = '\0';
      break;
   }
}
```

Comment: Whether or not your code works, you don't free the memory you allocated with malloc, which is a bad practice.  Memory leaks are not good.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 

Answer (score 0):

Don't have enough reputation to comment so add a answer here.

As Grijesh Chauhan [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21229214/how-to-get-the-directory-of-a-file-from-the-full-path-in-c#comment31975818_21229214) in question, you can use strrchr() to get a shorter version of your original string.

However, the return value of `strrchr()` is `char *`, which **SHOULD NOT** be assigned to `\0` that makes it **points to nothing**, instead, you can use `*` or `[0]` to modify it's first element to shorten the original string.

LIKE THIS:

```c
strrchr(File, '\\')[0] = '\0'

// or this
*(strrchr(File, '\\') = '\0'
```

Great answer though, Grijesh should make it a answer :D

Answer (score -1):

Here is a function that gets the full path and a buffer.
it will update the buffer to the parent path.
The function is checked. enjoy :)

```
/*
Use: Get parent path by full path
Input: full path, parent buffer
Output: None
*/
void getParent(char* path, char* parent)
{
    int parentLen;
    char* last = strrchr(path, '/');

    if (last != NULL) {

        parentLen = strlen(path) - strlen(last + 1);
        strncpy(parent, path, parentLen);
    }
}
```